# View blob file using react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to display a blob file with React. I am loading this from MySQL database beforehand and trying to display the file. Unfortunately I'am unable to do so, at the end I am always geting an error that the document could not be loaded (see image)

My function that should do that:

```
function download(dokument) {
 const file = new Blob([dokument], { type: "application/pdf" });

 //Build a URL from the file
 const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 //Open the URL on new Window
 window.open(fileURL);
}
```

[image]

[image]

****UPDATE*****

The file is a PDF file. The file is stored as a byte[] in MySQL using an entity and Spring Boot

```
 @PostMapping("/upload")
public void uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        HttpServletRequest req) {

    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Please select a file to upload");
        return;
    }

    try {

        String titel = req.getParameter("titel");
        String status = req.getParameter("status");
        String zugewiesenAn = req.getParameter("zugewiesenAn");

        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        Dokumente dokument = new Dokumente();
        dokument.setName(titel);
        dokument.setGesehen(0);
        dokument.setStatus(status);
        dokument.setZugewiesen(zugewiesenAn);
        dokument.setDatum(new Date());
        dokument.setUploadVon("Hans Maier");
        dokument.setDokument(bytes);
        dokument.setDokumentenTyp(file.getContentType());

        dokumentRepo.save(dokument);

        System.out.println("success");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: in order to get answers, you need to add more code and context to your question. How the file is stored? What kind of file?

Comment: The file is a PDF file. The file is stored as a byte[] in MySQL using an entity and Spring Boot

Comment: Can you share working code snippet, how are you saving the pdf blob file ?

Comment: Have edit post.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the document content, i think you might also need to give the `data:application/pdf;base64,`.

So your blob would look like
`data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJdDUxdgKNyAwIG9iago8....`

As in general base64 data would contain file information as well.

Code snippet -

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState();
  const previewFile = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("loadend", () => {
      console.log(reader.result);
      setFileData(reader.result);
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="file" onChange={previewFile} />
      <div>{fileData}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Suggestion: I would recommend you not to store pdfs in your database instead use some blob storage like S3 which are more suited for these use cases.